# SSIS error when inserting decimal values into MySQL 5.7 (Azure)

Tags: mysql, azure, ssis

I am attempting to create an ETL pipeline to load data from an on-premises, older MySQL database (5.1.61) into a MySQL for Azure instance running 5.7. I am using the ODBC provider.

Connections are configured and working for all cases except this: DECIMAL values cannot be inserted into tables anywhere. For example, a field defined as DECIMAL(7,2), which stores values like 1.50, will cause this error on insert:

```
Error: 0xC020844B at Data Flow Task, ADO NET Destination [2]: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: 
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

The error code 0xC020844B refers to this: "DTS_E_ADODESTINSERTIONFAILURE    An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: %".

I have tried multiple ODBC connectors of various versions, from early 5 up to 8.0.21. I get this same error regardless. I have tried data conversions or spoofing the values with derived columns, and that fails as well. Execute SQL tasks that directly do the insertion of values using an INSERT command will work, but obviously that is just to test whether I can insert decimal values at all over this ODBC connection.

I also have set all of the sql_mode parameters as defined for ANSI SQL (REAL_AS_FLOAT, PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ANSI_QUOTES, IGNORE_SPACE, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY).

Any help would be appreciated.